# Using array of Records in 'IN' operator in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am having a table Course which have column DepId and Course and some other value. I need to search this table for a some set of (DepId, Course). This set will be decided at runtime.

I want to write a single query in a procedure to fetch all the record pertaining to above set.
For example consider the table has data like

```
DepId Course  ...
------------------
   1       A
   2       B
   3       C
   4       D
   5       E
   6       F
```

Now only I want to search for below records:

```
DepId Course  ...
------------------
   1       A
   4       D
```

What would be most efficient way to write above query?
I was thinking of creating an Array of record and passing it in the 'IN' operator. But I was not able to get any example for this. Can someone guide me on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Leveraging Oracle Collections to Build Array-typed Solutions

The answer to your question is **YES**, dimensioned variables such as `ARRAYS` and `COLLECTIONS` are viable data types in solving problems where there are multiple values in either or both the input and output values.

> Additional good news is that the discussion for a simple example (such as the one in the OP) is pretty much the same as for a complex one.  Solutions built with arrays are nicely scalable and dynamic if designed with a little advanced planning.

### Some Up Front Design Decisions

- There are actual collection types called `ARRAYS` and `ASSOCIATIVE ARRAYS`.  I chose to use `NESTED TABLE TYPES` because of their accessibility to direct `SQL` queries.  In some ways, they exhibit "array-like" behavior.  There are other trade-offs which can be researched through Oracle references.
- The query applied to search the `COURSE TABLE` would apply a `JOIN` condition instead of an `IN-LIST` approach.
- The use of a `STORED PROCEDURE` typed object improves database response.  Queries within the procedure call can leverage and reuse already compiled code plus their cached execution plans.

### Choosing the Right Collection or Array Type

There are a lot of choices of collection types in Oracle for storing variables into memory.  Each has an advantage and some sort of limitation. [AskTom from Oracle](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2599785900346735561) has a good example and break-down of what a developer can expect by choosing one variable collection type over another.

### Using NESTED TABLE Types for Managing Multiple Valued Variables

For this solution,  I chose to work with `NESTED TABLES` because of their ability to be accessed directly through `SQL` commands.  After trying several different approaches, I noticed that the plain-SQL accessibility leads to more clarity in the resulting code.

The down-side is that you will notice that there is a little overhead here and there with respect to declaring an instance of a *nested table type*, initializing each instance, and managing its size with the addition of new values.

> In any case, if you anticipate a unknown number of input variables or values (our output), an array-typed data type (collection) of any sort is a more flexible structure for your code.  It is likely to require less maintenance in the end.

### The Example: A Stored Procedure Search Query

**Custom TYPE Definitions**

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE  "COURSE_REC_TYPE" IS OBJECT (DEPID NUMBER(10,0), COURSE VARCHAR2(10));

 CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE  "COURSE_TBL_TYPE" IS TABLE of course_rec_type;
```

**PROCEDURE Source Code**

```
 create or replace PROCEDURE ZZ_PROC_COURSE_SEARCH IS

    my_input   course_tbl_type:= course_tbl_type();
    my_output  course_tbl_type:= course_tbl_type();
    cur_loop_counter   pls_integer;

    c_output_template   constant  varchar2(100):=
        'DEPID: <<DEPID>>,  COURSE: <<COURSE>>';
    v_output   VARCHAR2(200);

    CURSOR find_course_cur IS           
       SELECT crs.depid, crs.course
         FROM zz_course crs,
             (SELECT depid, course
                FROM TABLE (CAST (my_input AS course_tbl_type))
                ) search_values
        WHERE crs.depid = search_values.depid
          AND crs.course = search_values.course;

 BEGIN
    my_input.extend(2);
    my_input(1):= course_rec_type(1, 'A');
    my_input(2):= course_rec_type(4, 'D');

    cur_loop_counter:= 0;
    for i in find_course_cur
    loop
       cur_loop_counter:= cur_loop_counter + 1;
       my_output.extend;
       my_output(cur_loop_counter):= course_rec_type(i.depid, i.course);

    end loop;

 for j in my_output.first .. my_output.last
 loop
     v_output:= replace(c_output_template, '<<DEPID>>', to_char(my_output(j).depid));
     v_output:= replace(v_output, '<<COURSE>>', my_output(j).course);

     dbms_output.put_line(v_output);

 end loop;

 end ZZ_PROC_COURSE_SEARCH;
```

**Procedure OUTPUT:**

```
 DEPID: 1,  COURSE: A
 DEPID: 4,  COURSE: D

 Statement processed.


 0.03 seconds
```

**MY COMMENTS:**  I wasn't particularly satisfied with the way the input variables were stored.  There was a clumsy kind of problem with "loading" values into the nested table structure... If you can consider using a single search key instead of a composite pair (i.e., depid and course), the problem condenses to a simpler form.

### Revised Cursor Using a Single Search Value

This is the proposed modification to the table design of the OP.  Add a single unique key id column (`RecId`) to represent each unique combination of `DepId` and `Course`.

[image: Proposed Table Structure Change: ZZ_COURSE_NEW]

Note that the RecId column represents a `SURROGATE KEY` which should have no internal meaning aside from its property as a uniquely assigned value.

**Custom TYPE Definitions**

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE  "NUM_TBL_TYPE" IS TABLE of INTEGER;
```

**Remove Array Variable**

This will be passed directly through an input parameter from the procedure call.

```
 -- REMOVE
 my_input   course_tbl_type:= course_tbl_type();
```

**Loading and Presenting INPUT Parameter Array (Nested Table)**

The following can be removed from the main procedure and presented as part of the call to the procedure.

```
 BEGIN
    my_input.extend(2);
    my_input(1):= course_rec_type(1, 'A');
    my_input(2):= course_rec_type(4, 'D');
```

Becomes:

```
 create or replace PROCEDURE ZZ_PROC_COURSE_SEARCH (p_search_ids IN num_tbl_type) IS...
```

and

```
 my_external_input.extend(2);
 my_external_input:= num_tbl_type(1, 4);
```

**Changing the Internal Cursor Definition**

The cursor looks about the same.  You can just as easily use an `IN-LIST` now that there is only one search parameter.

```
 CURSOR find_course_cur IS           
    SELECT crs.depid, crs.course
      FROM zz_course_new crs, 
           (SELECT column_value as recid
              FROM TABLE (CAST (p_search_ids AS num_tbl_type))
           ) search_values
     WHERE crs.recid = search_values.recid;
```

**The Actual SEARCH Call and Output**

The searching portion of this operation is now isolated and dynamic.  It does not need to be changed.  All the Changes happen in the calling PL/SQL block where the search ID values are a lot easier to read and change.

```
 DECLARE
    my_input_external   num_tbl_type:= num_tbl_type();

 BEGIN
    my_input_external.extend(3);
    my_input_external:= num_tbl_type(1,3,22);

    ZZ_PROC_COURSE_SEARCH (p_search_ids => my_input_external);

 END; 


 -- The OUTPUT (Currently set to DBMS_OUT)


 DEPID: 1,  COURSE: A
 DEPID: 4,  COURSE: D
 DEPID: 7,  COURSE: G

 Statement processed.

 0.01 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

This is something I havee used in the past in a situation similar to yours. Hopefully it helps.

The main benefit of this method would be that if you only passed it a single paramter it would still return all records for that single parameter. This way a single stored procedure with 5 input parameters could be used to search for all combinations of inputs.

Just call the stored procedure passing in the set and should return all values mathcing the criteria

- usp_custom_search '1','A'
- usp_custom_search '4','D'
- usp_custom_search '4',NULL
- usp_custom_search NULL,'A'
- etc

Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE custom_search (
    dep_id IN VARCHAR2,
    course_id IN VARCHAR2,
    result_set OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
BEGIN
    query_str VARCHAR2(1000);
    query_str := 'SELECT';
    query_str := query_str || ' DepId, Course';
    query_str := query_str || ' FROM Course';
    query_str := query_str || ' WHERE 1=1';
    IF (dep_id is not null) then query_str := query_str || ' AND DepId = ''' || dep_id || ''''; END IF;
    IF (course_id is not null) then query_str := query_str || ' AND Course = ''' || course_id || ''''; END IF;
    open result_set for query_str;
END custom_search;
/
```